# 128GB RAM as 8 x 16G or 16 x 8G?

Tags: memory

I am configuring a workstation for heavy and memory expensive numerical computing. I have the budget to put 128G of RAM. I have the choice between eight 16Gb modules or 16 8Gb modules. Both configs are about the same price.
Is there a reason why I should prefer one over the other.
I am using two CPU's Xeon E5-2643 3.30Ghz 4cores

Comment: I assume the motherboard as 16 memory module slots.  If you only use 8 of those 16 then you are left with 8 additional modules you can use in the future.

Comment: Might help to state the motherboard type. I remember that some of the SF folk mentioned that the *order* the ram is in is important, as would the maximum amount of ram on it

Comment: is that all there is to it ? There are no potential performance issues etc. with using the larger 16G modules ? Reliability ? Addressability ?

Comment: @MathiasVanwolleghem - There is pleanty of research on the subject.  You asked for a reason so I provided one to you.

Comment: As @Journeyman Geek noted, we could use more info on the board.  You should be able to find a suggested RAM configuration for the motherboard to assure best performance and best future upgradability.